# No entiendo este error ==> NameError: name 'pr' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, funcion

No se porque me dice que pr no esta definido si es el nombre de una funcion (la segunda)
La funcion arroz en sí va bien, el problema es que cuando dentro de esta llamo a la otra funcion [def pr()] me dice que no esta definida

```
def arroz():
   
    casilla=1
    suma=0
    while casilla <=64:
        suma+=2**(casilla)
        print('-'*24)
        print('===> Centimos en casilla',casilla,'=',(2**casilla))
        print()
        print('===> Centimos totales =',suma)
        print()
        casilla+=1
    euros=int(suma/100)
    billones=int(euros//10**12)
    millones=int((euros-billones*(10**12))//10**6)
    resta=euros-billones*(10**12)-millones*(10**6)
    B=pr(billones)
    M=pr(millones)
    R=pr(resta)
    print('Traducido sería:')
    print('='*46)
    print(B,'Billones',M,'Millones',R,'Euros |')
    print('='*46)

arroz()
   
def pr(x):

    n=str(x) #conversion del num a txt 
    i=len(n)
    res=''  #resultado (num con puntos)
    cont=0  #poner punto cada 3 cifras
     
    while i:
        if cont==3:
            res='.'+res
            cont=0
        res=n[i-1]+res
        
        cont+=1
        i-=1
    print(res)
    return res
```

Answer (score 2):

Es simple: los nombres (de funciones, variables, lo que sea) tienen que estar definidos antes de usarlo.

En tu código primero llamas a la función `pr()` y después la defines. Python procesa el código línea a línea, y cuando se encuentra con `pr()` todavía no ve la definición.

**Solución**

Corre la definición de la función al comienzo del código:

```
def pr(x):
    n = str(x)  # conversion del num a txt
    i = len(n)
    res = ''  # resultado (num con puntos)
    cont = 0  # poner punto cada 3 cifras

    while i:
        if cont == 3:
            res = '.' + res
            cont = 0
        res = n[i - 1] + res

        cont += 1
        i -= 1
    print(res)
    return res


casilla = 1
suma = 0
while casilla <= 64:
    suma += 2 ** (casilla)
    print('-' * 24)
    print('===> Centimos en casilla', casilla, '=', (2 ** casilla))
    print()
    print('===> Centimos totales =', suma)
    print()
    casilla += 1
euros = int(suma / 100)
billones = int(euros // 10 ** 12)
millones = int((euros - billones * (10 ** 12)) // 10 ** 6)
resta = euros - billones * (10 ** 12) - millones * (10 ** 6)
B = pr(billones)
M = pr(millones)
R = pr(resta)
print('Traducido sería:')
print('=' * 46)
print(B, 'Billones', M, 'Millones', R, 'Euros |')
print('=' * 46)
```

produce:

```
------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 1 = 2

===> Centimos totales = 2

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 2 = 4

===> Centimos totales = 6

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 3 = 8

===> Centimos totales = 14

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 4 = 16

===> Centimos totales = 30

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 5 = 32

===> Centimos totales = 62

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 6 = 64

===> Centimos totales = 126

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 7 = 128

===> Centimos totales = 254

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 8 = 256

===> Centimos totales = 510

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 9 = 512

===> Centimos totales = 1022

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 10 = 1024

===> Centimos totales = 2046

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 11 = 2048

===> Centimos totales = 4094

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 12 = 4096

===> Centimos totales = 8190

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 13 = 8192

===> Centimos totales = 16382

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 14 = 16384

===> Centimos totales = 32766

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 15 = 32768

===> Centimos totales = 65534

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 16 = 65536

===> Centimos totales = 131070

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 17 = 131072

===> Centimos totales = 262142

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 18 = 262144

===> Centimos totales = 524286

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 19 = 524288

===> Centimos totales = 1048574

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 20 = 1048576

===> Centimos totales = 2097150

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 21 = 2097152

===> Centimos totales = 4194302

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 22 = 4194304

===> Centimos totales = 8388606

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 23 = 8388608

===> Centimos totales = 16777214

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 24 = 16777216

===> Centimos totales = 33554430

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 25 = 33554432

===> Centimos totales = 67108862

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 26 = 67108864

===> Centimos totales = 134217726

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 27 = 134217728

===> Centimos totales = 268435454

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 28 = 268435456

===> Centimos totales = 536870910

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 29 = 536870912

===> Centimos totales = 1073741822

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 30 = 1073741824

===> Centimos totales = 2147483646

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 31 = 2147483648

===> Centimos totales = 4294967294

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 32 = 4294967296

===> Centimos totales = 8589934590

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 33 = 8589934592

===> Centimos totales = 17179869182

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 34 = 17179869184

===> Centimos totales = 34359738366

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 35 = 34359738368

===> Centimos totales = 68719476734

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 36 = 68719476736

===> Centimos totales = 137438953470

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 37 = 137438953472

===> Centimos totales = 274877906942

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 38 = 274877906944

===> Centimos totales = 549755813886

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 39 = 549755813888

===> Centimos totales = 1099511627774

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 40 = 1099511627776

===> Centimos totales = 2199023255550

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 41 = 2199023255552

===> Centimos totales = 4398046511102

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 42 = 4398046511104

===> Centimos totales = 8796093022206

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 43 = 8796093022208

===> Centimos totales = 17592186044414

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 44 = 17592186044416

===> Centimos totales = 35184372088830

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 45 = 35184372088832

===> Centimos totales = 70368744177662

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 46 = 70368744177664

===> Centimos totales = 140737488355326

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 47 = 140737488355328

===> Centimos totales = 281474976710654

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 48 = 281474976710656

===> Centimos totales = 562949953421310

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 49 = 562949953421312

===> Centimos totales = 1125899906842622

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 50 = 1125899906842624

===> Centimos totales = 2251799813685246

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 51 = 2251799813685248

===> Centimos totales = 4503599627370494

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 52 = 4503599627370496

===> Centimos totales = 9007199254740990

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 53 = 9007199254740992

===> Centimos totales = 18014398509481982

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 54 = 18014398509481984

===> Centimos totales = 36028797018963966

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 55 = 36028797018963968

===> Centimos totales = 72057594037927934

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 56 = 72057594037927936

===> Centimos totales = 144115188075855870

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 57 = 144115188075855872

===> Centimos totales = 288230376151711742

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 58 = 288230376151711744

===> Centimos totales = 576460752303423486

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 59 = 576460752303423488

===> Centimos totales = 1152921504606846974

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 60 = 1152921504606846976

===> Centimos totales = 2305843009213693950

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 61 = 2305843009213693952

===> Centimos totales = 4611686018427387902

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 62 = 4611686018427387904

===> Centimos totales = 9223372036854775806

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 63 = 9223372036854775808

===> Centimos totales = 18446744073709551614

------------------------
===> Centimos en casilla 64 = 18446744073709551616

===> Centimos totales = 36893488147419103230

368.934
881.474
191.040
Traducido sería:
==============================================
368.934 Billones 881.474 Millones 191.040 Euros |
==============================================
```

Answer (score 0):

Te da el error porque la tienes definida debajo de la función arroz, si hicieses lo mismo con cualquier variable te pasaría lo mismo.

Si la pones encima no te dará ese problema.

Comment: "Encima" no sirve. Tiene que ponerla antes de las llamadas a `pr()`